What is the translation of "overhead transport system" in French?
Example of an overhead transport system:

What is the translation of "overhead transport system" in French?


Google Translate says: "système de transport aérien", which sounds ambiguous to me, as aérien may refer to planes (e.g., compagnie aérienne).
linguee.com returns "système de transport suspendu au plafond". I wonder if "suspendu au plafond" can be shortened.


I think you forgot a copy paste in your question, this isn't about GPU as far as I know

@TeleportingGoat fixed, thanks!

I would simply use:

"convoyeur" for the transport system
"suspendu" for the overhead part

So: "Convoyeur suspendu" seems like the shortest form, and probably the most accurate.
For instance, the Wuppertaler Schwebebahn is defined as "train suspendu" or "monorail suspendu", and has a similar mode of operation.

Selon l’OQLF, on peut traduire « automated overhead conveyor system » par :

système de convoyage aérien informatisé

système de manutention en suspendu informatisé

système de convoyage aérien

système de manutention en suspendu


Source
Donc si on laisse tomber « automated », si vous trouvez que « aérien » est ambigu et que « suspendu au plafond » est trop long, alors la dernière traduction devrait faire l’affaire : « système de manutention en suspendu ».

on dirait que le terme "convoyeur" (et notamment convoyeur aérien) est assez utilisé, c'est quand même plus simple que "système de...". Voir ici par ex : https://www.oca.fr/ "(...)réalisons et installons des convoyeurs aériens et machines spéciales, manuels ou automatisés, destinés à faciliter la manutention, le transport et le stockage de charges (allant de quelques centaines de grammes à près de 10 tonnes)"
